# Cannot open '.git/FETCH_HEAD': no such file or directory

Tags: flutter, git

After I installed flutter,vs code and git I set up the paths and try to run flutter create app in my terminal but the error is: Cannot open '.git/FETCH_HEAD': no such file or directory

I thought after I set all the path it should create the path of my project

Comment: Are you following the install instructions on flutter.dev exactly?  For what platform?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.